# Access form fields in InlineFormSets

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

If you override `forms.ModelForms` you easily can access it form fields, like:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name']
```

How to do the same thing with Formsets, like `forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet`?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom form and pass that as the `form` argument to `inlineformset_factory`.